# JS Validation for Select multiple

Tags: javascript, validation, html-select

Here is the issue with Select multiple and JS validation:

```
<select name="service_ids[]" id="service_ids" size="7" multiple="">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="1">S1</option>
    .
    .
    .
</select>
```

The issue is that if a user selects multiple options including first option, then the follow wont work:

1. `document.getElementById('service_ids').selectedIndex => 0`
2. `document.getElementById('service_ids').value => empty`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this

```
var services=document.getElementById('service_ids');

for(i=0;i<services.length;i++){
  if(services.opstions[i].selected&&sevices.optins[i].value=''){
    alert('This one should not be selected!');
    break; // or return false
  }
}
```

You can put this code in function that validates input before submiting

**UPDATE**

In case you only care that first option should not be selected, you can check it like this

```
if(document.getElementById('service_ids').options[0].selected){
     alert('This should not be selected');
}
```

If you don't get alert you can submit form and on the server side get selected values

Comment: You can always use jQuery with selector `$('#service_ids option:selected')` to get more readable code, or `$('#service_ids option[value='']:selected')` which returns undefined if first option is not selected

Comment: In that case my answer remains. I would also like to see other solution for this beside loop